# Getting all rows where one column is in a set within the same table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join

So I've got a MySQL table with the following columns:

```
PROPERTY_ID
AGENT_ID
STATUS
SALE_DATE
SALE_PRICE
ZIP
```

I want to get the total sales for all agents who have sold at least one property in a given ZIP code.  Meaning, if Bob Smith's AGENT_ID is linked to at least one property in ZIP 90210, then I want all of Bob Smith's sales included in the total.

I know I can do this in multiple steps with something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `AGENTS` (`AGENT_ID` INT);
INSERT INTO `AGENTS` SELECT DISTINCT `AGENT_ID` FROM `PROPERTIES` WHERE ZIP = 90210;
SELECT SUM(p.`SALE_PRICE`) FROM `PROPERTIES` p, `AGENTS` a WHERE p.`AGENT_ID` = a.`AGENT_ID`;
```

What I'm wondering is, can I accomplish this without dumping the agent IDs into a temporary table to join on?  It seems like there would be a way to join the PROPERTIES table on itself for this purpose but I'm not sure how.  Any ideas would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you don't actually need a `JOIN` and can accomplish this with a select in the where clause.  The `IN` clause gives you all agents who've sold anything in 90210, but doesn't limit the results of the `SUM()` to those property records in 90210.

```
SELECT SUM(SALE_PRICE) 
FROM properties
WHERE AGENT_ID IN (SELECT AGENT_ID FROM properties WHERE ZIP = 90210);
```

If you want sums of each individual agent, add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AGENT_ID, SUM(SALE_PRICE) 
FROM properties
WHERE AGENT_ID IN (SELECT AGENT_ID FROM properties WHERE ZIP = 90210)
GROUP BY AGENT_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    AGENT_ID,
    SUM(SALE_PRICE)
FROM PROPERTIES
WHERE AGENT_ID IN (SELECT AGENT_ID FROM PROPERTIES WHERE ZIP = 90210)
GROUP BY AGENT_ID;
```

This will give a separate total for each agent that sold something in 90210.
Although you question doesn't say this, it suggests this is what you want.

Comment: This sent me in the right direction, although I actually just need the TOTAL sum, not by agent, so I can do away with the GROUP BY.